# Angular 6 - Event - How to stop adding duplicate record

Tags: angular

Angular 6

I have a problem similar to this scenario

I have a dropdown with list of values.
And if I add an existing record, I want to alert the user it already exists.

However, in my code, it alerts duplicate record but still adds the record.

Code: https://stackblitz.com/edit/jay-angular-primeng-qhxqsk

**Update:-**

Thanks guys, you answer helped me. 
Is there are any difference between the below 2 blocks?  The first block works but now the second one.

```
if (this.model.lines.some(row => row.ENT_COU_RES.CodeValue === countryCode)) {}
```

And

```
if (this.model.lines.some((row) => { row.ENT_COU_RES.CodeValue === countryCode })) { }
```

Comment: The first block (without the braces) will return that value. As soon as you add the `{}`. you also need to add the `return` keyword, otherwise it will return undefined.

Comment: Many thanks very helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your return statement only returns from the `forEach`, not the `addCountry` function.

Instead, you can do:

```ts
  addCountry(newCountry) {
    console.log("xx : " + JSON.stringify(newCountry));

    if (this.lines.some((country) => country.name === newCountry.name)) {
      alert('already exists ...');
    } else {
      this.lines.push(newCountry);
    } 

    console.log("lines : " + JSON.stringify(this.lines));
  }
```

**[Here is a fork of the Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/jay-angular-primeng-6xhd5n?file=src/app/app.component.ts)**

Answer (score 1):

Use the `find` operator`instead of`foreach`

```
let exist = this.lines.find((country) => country.name === newCountry.name)

if(exist){
    alert('already exists ...')
    return;
}
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/jay-angular-primeng-nhxzzb?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Answer (score 1):

Change your function like this..

```
  addCountry(newCountry) {
    console.log("xx : " + JSON.stringify(newCountry));

    if(this.lines.findIndex((x)=>x.name ==newCountry.name)>=0){
           alert('already exists ...')
    }else{
      this.lines.push(newCountry);
    }
   console.log("lines : " + JSON.stringify(this.lines));
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to maintain the variable and use that variable to check whether to add item in the list or not.

Please check below code,

```
addCountry(newCountry) {
    console.log("xx : " + JSON.stringify(newCountry));
    //Added found flag
    let found=false;
    this.lines.forEach(country => {
      if(country.name === newCountry.name) {
        alert('already exists ...')
        //Change found value if any similar item is found.
        found=true;
        return false;
      }
    });
    // Use found to decide whehter to add or not
    if(!found){
        this.lines.push(newCountry);
    }
    console.log("lines : " + JSON.stringify(this.lines));
  }
```

The reason behind this:

> Return statement inside forEach only return that forEach code block,
>   it will return main addCountry function.